# Test Class Query returning no rows for assignment

Tags: case, contact

I have a trigger that will tie a contact to a Case if that contact's email matches the cases supplied email (Web Email). Below is the basic trigger:

```
trigger TiePartnerContactToCase on Case (before insert) {



for (Case newPartnerSupportCase : Trigger.new){
    List<Contact> newPartnerSupportContacts = New List<Contact>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Email = :newPartnerSupportCase.SuppliedEmail LIMIT 1]);


    if (newPartnerSupportContacts.size() == 1 && newPartnerSupportCase.RecordTypeId == '012M000000092ju') {
        newPartnerSupportCase.ContactId = newPartnerSupportContacts[0].Id;
    }

    else{
        return;
    }


}
```

The problem that I am having is in my test class. the system.assert statement tells me that the list I am querying (the QueriedTestContact) has no rows for assignment. In the test class, I just created a contact where CaseId = :testCase.Id, so I do not understand why there are no rows for assignment. Below is the test Class:

```
@isTest
public class TiePartnerContactToCase_Test {

static testMethod void testContactTie() {

    Test.startTest();

    Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'testingAccount');

    Contact testContact = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestContactF', LastName = 'TestContactL', Email = 'sample-email@navinet.net', AccountId = TestAccount.Id);

    Case testCase = new Case(SuppliedEmail = 'sample-email@navinet.net', RecordTypeId = '012M000000092ju', AccountId = testAccount.Id, ContactId = testContact.Id);

    insert testCase;



    QueriedTestContact = [SELECT Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE CaseId = :testCase.Id];

    system.assertEquals(testCase.SuppliedEmail, QueriedTestContact.Email);

    Test.stopTest();



}



}
```

What I am looking to do, is make sure that my system.assert verifies the supplied email of the test case equals the TestContact's email address. Any help would go a long way.

Thank you,
-CP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `insert` of the `testContact`  Contact (and `testAccount` Account before that) is missing from your test.

Comment: That did it. It is telling me I must wait 7 minutes to mark the best answer, but you got it. Much appreciated.